# Тесты для функции

Tags: java

Есть функция для работы с переменной (полем) “Возраст студента”. КАК спроектировать  для этой функции любые кейсы (тесты) для верификации?

```
if (!studentAge.matches("\\d+") || 
        Integer.parseInt(studentAge) < 5 || 
        Integer.parseInt(studentAge) > 65) {

    System.out.println("Invalid Age!");
}
```

Comment: в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тесты - это контракт.

Для того чтобы спроектировать тесты, необходимо знать что должна делать функция и чего не должна.

В Вашем случае необходимо убедиться что функция делает то что Вы задумали - проверяет возраст студента.

Вот Ваш пример, в виде класса

```
public class Student {

    private String studentAge;

    public Student(String studentAge) {
        this.studentAge = studentAge;
    }

    public void checkAgeError() {
        if (!studentAge.matches("\\d+") || 
                Integer.parseInt(studentAge) < 5 || 
                Integer.parseInt(studentAge) > 65) {

            System.out.println("Invalid Age!");
        }
    }
}
```

Я назвал функцию `checkAgeError()` формальные unit-тесты для нее написать будет сложно т.к. функция содержит `System.out` которая является **сайд эффектом (side effect)**, для этой функции (т.к. название не отражает то, что функция что-то выведет) хоть и тип возвращаемого значение `void` неявно нам на это намекает. Но проблема не в наличии сайд эффекта а в его характере - вывод в консоль это `IO` (общение с подсистемой ввода-вывода) 
и ссылка на это поле использована статическая.

Что в этом плохого - как раз то, что cложно написать тест для этой функции, чтобы убедиться что она отработала корректно Вам необходимо иметь дело со статическим полем класса `System`, это сильно повезло что `System.out` можно перезадать на свой `OutputStream`, а не на вывод в консоль и узнать что туда было записано в рамках вызова тестового метода.

Чтобы этого не делать надо немного перепроектировать функцию, чтобы она возвращала результат проверки, а не выводила текст в консоль.

```
public void checkAgeError() {
    return !studentAge.matches("\\d+") || 
         Integer.parseInt(studentAge) < 5 || 
         Integer.parseInt(studentAge) > 65;
}
```

Теперь выводить в консоль нужно в том месте, где вызывается функция `checkAge()` а не внутри нее, и мы можем легко написать unit-тесты к этой функции.

Какой тут контракт?

1. Возраст должен быть задан числом
2. Возраст должен быть в диапазоне 5-65

Так как логика функции инвертирована (проверяем некорректность а не корректность :) ) необходимо проверить, что при корректных входных значениях даст отрицательный результат а в некорректных - положительный, это и сделаем, в этом примере код для тестового фреймворка JUnit4:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class StudentTest {

    @Test
    public void checkAgeDataType() {
        assertTrue( "must return true when age is not number",
                new Student("").checkAgeNotMatch());
    }

    @Test
    public void checkAgeMin() {
        assertTrue( "must return true when age is lower than 5",
                new Student("4").checkAgeNotMatch());
    }

    @Test
    public void checkAgeMax() {
        assertTrue( "must return true when age is greater than 65",
                new Student("66").checkAgeNotMatch());
    }

    @Test
    public void checkAgeInterval6() {
        assertFalse( "must return false when age is number between 5 and 65",
                new Student("6").checkAgeNotMatch());
    }

    @Test
    public void checkAgeInterval64() {
        assertFalse( "must return false when age is number between 5 and 65",
                new Student("64").checkAgeNotMatch());
    }

    // так же возможно проверка поведения с выбросом исключения
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void checkAgeIsNull() {
        assertTrue( "must throw npe when number is null",
                new Student(null).checkAgeNotMatch());
    }
}
```

Теперь, когда функция `checkAgeNotMatch` сломается по какой-либо причине, должен упасть какой-о из тестов, но для этого нужно их постоянно запускать

PS: это очень простой пример, тут нет `mock` объектов, которым можно было бы закрыть `System.out`, однако не буду я тут писать целую книгу..., извините что может быть слегка сумбурно, давайте вместе поправим, если что-то запутано написано =)