# Как протестировать метод в JUnit?

Tags: java, javafx, junit

а именно как проверить метод `coding()` ?

```
public class Proger extends Human {
    private static final int RAND_SIZE = 150;
    private final int MIN_RAND = 50;
    private final String alphabet = ("QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890(){}[]<>=!,");

    public Proger() {
        super();
    }

    public Proger (String name) {
        super (name);
    }

    public String coding() {
        int size = new Random().nextInt(RAND_SIZE) + MIN_RAND;
        String code = "";
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            char next_symbol = alphabet.charAt (new Random().nextInt(alphabet.length()));
            code += next_symbol;
        }
        return code;
    }

    public void eat(ArrayList<Food> foodList) {
        Food f = foodList.get (foodList.size()-1);
        foodList.remove(foodList.size()-1);
        Alert alert = new Alert (Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        alert.setTitle ("Вкусно!");
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText("Кажется, вкус этого блюда: " + f.tasteToString().toLowerCase()+"\n"+
                "Было вкусно, но бывало и получше");
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
}
```

Comment: недавно писал ответ на аналогичный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962083/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: Во-первых, из метода coding нужно вынести random функциональности в два метода. И тогда что так и как делать Random становится совсем не интересно, потому что работа двух этих методов может заменена на любой фейковый (заранее созданный) результат, с помощью которого уже элементарно проверить результат работы метода. Разумеется для этого потребуется библиотека Mockito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для тестирования методов, которые опираются на недетерменированные данные, вводят дополнительный уровень косвенности, чтобы разорвать связь.

В случае с классом `Random` это делается в два этапа.

1. Мы не создаём объект класса `Random` непосредственно, а получаем его экземпляр в конструкторе.

```java
private Random random;

public Proger(Random random) {
    super();

    this.random = random;
}

public String coding() {
    int size = random.nextInt(RAND_SIZE) + MIN_RAND;
    String code = "";

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        char next_symbol = alphabet.charAt (random.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
        code += next_symbol;
    }

    return code;
}
```

В коде мы используем механизм *внедрения зависимостей* для создания экземпляров классов.

2. В тестовом коде мы создаём своего наследника класса `Random` и переопределяем метод `nextInt`, например, так, чтобы он всегда возвращал 10. Поскольку метод `nextInt` не объявлен как `final`, мы можем это сделать. Наш экземпляр `Random` называется *заглушкой* (stub).

Мы создаём в тестовом методе экземпляр `Proger` и передаём ему нашу заглушку в конструкторе. После этого метод `coding` должен возвращать *детерменированные* данные, а именно строку из 60-ти символов 'A', если я правильно всё посчитал.

Ещё раз отмечу, что всё это работает, если вы применяете при организации программы принцип *инверсии зависимостей* (dependency inversion) и используете библиотеку *внедрения зависимостей* (dependency injection).

Answer (score 0):

поскольку этот метод рандомный, то можно протестировать на не-null и на ненулевую длину строки.

```
@Test
    public void shouldReturnNonNullValue() {
        Proger proger = new Proger();
        assertNotNull(proger.coding());
    }

@Test
    public void shouldReturnStringWithLengthMoreTHanOne(){
        Proger proger = new Proger();
        assertTrue(proger.coding().length()>1);
    }
```